# Problem with Regex "The string is outside the <li></li>" Python

Tags: python, regex, python-re

I need to get string which are not attachments.
(Is not between `<li></li>`)

Example:

```
i need this string!
<div>i need this string too!</div>
:)<li>I don't need this string!</li>:)
```

Result:

```
i need this string!
<div>i need this string too!</div>
:):)
```

I tried this:

```
^(?!<li>.*$).*(?<!<\/li>)
```

But the problem is that if there is text next to my string
`<li>text</li>`
For example a smiley:

```
:)<li>I don't need this string!</li>:)
```

then the pattern does not work and I don’t understand how to fix it.
Can you correct me please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `re.sub()` to remove the string you don't want, instead of trying to match everything else.

```
result = re.sub('<li>.*?</li>', '', text);
```